# how to make scale css just image

Tags: html, css

I need to zoom in on the image, but I'm using `background-url` would be the equivalent of:

```
.fakeImg:hover img{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

but I only want the image to grow inside the `div`

**current state:**

[image]

**objective:**

[image]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkw1rcnx/11/)

Comment: Add `overflow: hidden` to `.imgblog`

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the `background-size` instead of `scale` to change **only** the `background-image`

```css
.box {
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 margin:50px;
 border:2px solid red;
 background-image:url("https://picsum.photos/400/400?image=1068");
 background-size:100% 100%;
 background-position:center;
 transition:1s all;
}
.box:hover {
 background-size:130% 130%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The scaling will work but you need to set `overflow: hidden` to the parent (frame) of your image.

Here is an example:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/658687/pexels-photo-658687.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  transition: 1s all;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Transform is preferred over altering background-size.

Comment: @DevinFields accepted or not it's up to the asker to decide, but can you explain why transform is preferred? :) ... you may notice that transform will transfrom **all** the element, including border, content, shadow, everything ... but background size will only change the background-image which is what is needed here ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif scale, in combination with overflow:hidden, will do exactly what he wants, and with better performance since transforms do not cause new layouts: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Is it that huge of a deal in this case? No, but perhaps, as his projects grow, these little things may add up.

Comment: @DevinFields the link you shared is exactly what I need :) because if you read it again you will see that background also doens't trigger a new layout ;) there is only one step more than the transform so the difference of performance isn't an issue at all ... And I know that scale in this case will do exactly what needed but I simply don't agree with the word *preferred* for a more generic case :) .. well, this is a matter of opinion at the end ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I mentioned layout specifically, but as you said, there are more steps than that. You should be careful not to underestimate the impact repaints can potentially have. If you're working with something that will frequently move, you can see a sharp increase in cpu usage. I doubt that in this specific case, I just personally would animate outside of those four properties as sparingly as possible.